# How to remove mapped network drive when created with a random letter

Tags: powershell

I am creating a mapped network drive with a random letter like this:

```
 $drive = Get-ChildItem function:[f-z]: -n | Where { !(Test-Path $_) } | select -First 1
 $PsDrive = New-PSDrive -Name ($drive)[0] -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root $somePath
```

This code works fine. I have a problem when want to remove the newly created mapped drive at the end of my script. How I do it:

```
$someEnv = Remove-PSDrive -Name $drive
```

The problem here is that **$drive** adds the colon after the name '**:**'. For example if **$drive** is called **M**, it will be "**M:**" and **Remove-PsDrive** fails.

Probably it will be removed automatically when the session is over, but I want to remove it explicitly.

Do you guys have an idea how I can remove this drive?

Thanks

Comment: you can use the `.TrimEnd()` string method to remove unwanted stuff from the end of the string value. [*grin*]

Comment: Why don't you use the same syntax you used to create the mapped drive? ;-)

Comment: also, the `New-PSDrive` cmdlet _does not require a colon_. [*grin*] you can just name it `k` and it will accept it. so your "index number zero` solution will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the ':' from the $drive variable using Replace

```
$drive.Replace(':','')
```

So your code to remove the drive looks like this

```
$someEnv = Remove-PSDrive -Name  $drive.Replace(':','')
```

Answer (score 2):

here is another, somewhat different way to do it that uses just powershell. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates a list of possible drive letters
  in this case, it is just `F` thru `Z`.
  == uses `'F'[0]` to convert the letter string to a character
  == uses the range operator to coerce the chars to ascii code numbers
  == generates a range from those code numbers
  == coerces the code numbers back to characters & stuffs them into an array
  in PoSh7, you can make that array with `'F'..'Z'`. [*grin*]
- grabs the in-use drive letters
- filters the candidate letters against the in-use letters
- grabs the 1st remaining letter
- sets a target root
  in this case it is the temp dir.
- creates a new PSDrive with that letter
- shows the drive letter in use by that new PSDrive
- gets a dir list of the 1st three items in that PSDrive
- removes the PSDrive
- shows the current filesystem PSDrives

the code ...

```
$CandidateDriveLetters = [char[]]('F'[0]..'Z'[0])
$InUseDriveLetters = (Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Name
$1stAvailableDL = ($CandidateDriveLetters |
    Where-Object {
        $_ -notin $InUseDriveLetters
        })[0]

$TargetDriveRoot = $env:TEMP
$NewDrive = New-PSDrive -Name $1stAvailableDL -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $TargetDriveRoot

$NewDrive.Name
'=' * 30
Get-ChildItem -Path ('{0}:' -f $NewDrive.Name) |
    Select-Object -First 3

'=' * 30
Remove-PSDrive -Name $NewDrive.Name

(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Name
```

output ...

```
H
==============================


    Directory: C:\Temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2020-04-21   6:39 PM                2ccdytd4
d-----       2020-04-21   6:39 PM                30u23uyw
d-----       2020-04-21   6:39 PM                55zoq3fj
==============================
C
D
E
F
G
R
S
Z
```